# How can I use WSUS in a Windows Workgroup?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows-server-2008-r2, wsus

Essentially I was wondering if it's possible to use the local gpedit.msc on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2 machines to configure clients to use a workgroup based WSUS installation. With this - I would still like to ensure users can use Windows Update manually but the WSUS does the majority of the work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Registry

Please see the article [Configure Automatic Updates in a Non–Active Directory Environment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708449(v=ws.10)).

1. You're going to want to set these registry keys to the URL for your WSUS server (for example: `http://wsus.local`):

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUServer
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUStatusServer
   ```

   <sup>Note: The key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate` does not exist on a fresh installation of Windows 7. You will have to create it if it doesn't exist.</sup>
2. Then create a new DWORD named `UseWUServer` in the following key and set it to `1`:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
   ```

This should be enough to tell the system to use your local WSUS installation.

Please see the article linked above for further options in configuring the Windows Update behavior.

#### Example

These are the default settings a Windows Small Business Server 2010 will set:
[image]
[image]

### Group Policy

It should also be noted that these settings are also accessible through the **Local Group Policy Editor** under `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Update`:
[[image]

<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTqe1.png)

In the group policy editor, we can also see the group policy that may be used to restrict access to Windows Update for a user. This would allow installation only directly through WSUS approval and automatic installation (which would have to be configured):
[[image]

<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbgHM.png)

Comment: Would that by default go ahead and use WSUS, but still allow manual Windows Update checks?

Comment: @TheD: It should. The access to Microsofts own update servers would have to be disabled separately.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUServer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUStatusServer - Do I need to create these keys and folders? They don't exist in my Win7 box ?

Comment: @TheD: The part up until `Microsoft\Windows` should exist, otherwise I would be a bit confused. If the *folder* `WindowsUpdate` does not exist, create it.

Comment: Sorry yes, should of been more specific with that! Yeah, it's just the WindowsUpdate which doesn't. Cheers!

Comment: Many thanks again for the very detailed answer, I wish I could rate it twice!

Comment: It's been about 10mins now, my machine's dont appear to be checking into WSUS, even after a restart?

Comment: @TheD: To make sure your clients are using the correct server and aren't having any issues, check `%WINDIR%\WindowsUpdate.log` (be sure to start at the end). Also, I still remember my own WSUS issues vividly: http://serverfault.com/questions/390639/should-my-wsus-provide-update-information-before-it-is-fully-synchronized If you need more help, find me on [chat] :)

Comment: It takes days (1 to 10) for WSUS clients to start working properly, just be patient